# C++ While loop questions

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have some problems on how to set while and do/while cycles.

For example, i have a problem, where in input i have 2 int numbers ( let's call them a,b ) and i need to calculate a sum. The sum is particolar: a + (b) + (b – 1) + (b – 2) + … + 0. The while cicle is a must. But i don't know how to set it. I have tried, but I don't know if it is right. Can somebody let me know this?

Here there is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 // Variables
 int a,b;
 int sum;

 cout<<"Insert a:";
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"Insert b:";
 cin>>b;

 // Show a,b
 cout<<"variables:"<<" "<<a<<" e "<<b<<endl;

// Condition: a>0 & b>0
while(a>0 && b>0)
{
 sum=a+b;
 b--;  
} cout<<"Sum:"<<sum;
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}
```

For example if i put a=5 and b=9 the sum is 6. Is it right?

Comment: initialize the sum variable `int sum = 0;`

Comment: Yes, your code will set `sum` to 6, but that is not what your requirement states it should be.

Comment: @UnholySheep and so what should i do in this while cicle? thanks

Comment: Change it so it does what is required. (Here's a hint, initialize `sum` to 0 and in the `while` use the `+=` operator) Also since this appears to be homework you could (and should) ask your teacher for clarification

Comment: Assuming both a and b are > 0

sum = a;
while(b>0)
{
 sum += b;
 b--;  
}
cout<<"Sum: "<<sum;

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan thank you! what does sum+=b do exactly?

Comment: sum += b; is the same as sum = sum + b; Thats what you need in your case, since you have to keep the previous values that while has given.

Comment: you can also replace those two lines of {sum += b; b--;} with { sum += b--; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might think of rewriting the while portion. I would suggest you to check only `b` in while condition. Because, you are changing the `b` value only. Please see the following code -

```
sum = a; // as you want to add a only once, you should add a to sum before the loop
while(b)
{
 sum += b;
 b--;  
}
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any confusions.

Answer (score 0):

You must set `sum = a;` before entering the `while` loop and update it in each iteration as `sum += b;`. Hopefully these will solve your issue.